# Visual Studio 2017 tool to generate VB.NET classes from a database?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. What is the best tool for creating a set of VB.NET classes so that each class represents a table on the database with a property for each column? Or is there a better recommended method for mapping database tables to VB.NET classes?

Comment: Search for Entity Framework

Comment: Hans, Does that work with Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Oh yes, it has been a part of the .Net environment for years. See [an intro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723.aspx)